# How to insert image into mysql workbench using sql query? I have tried with LOAD_FILE but it ends up with error with null value

Tags: mysql, database, image, blob, mysql-workbench

I created a table named as product and the product picture is defined as LONGBLOB datatype.

```
CREATE TABLE `product`.`product` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `product_category` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `product_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `product_description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `product_pic` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`));
```

```
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('01', 'Ram Hoodies', '59.00', 'Clothes', '2020-12-27', 'Ram Hoodies which just brought two monthss ago', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/jacket-ram.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('02', 'Cooker', '159.00', 'Household Appliances', '2020-12-27', 'A multicooker which is still new but I don\'t use it frequently', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/cooker.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('03', 'Guitar', '159.00', 'Others', '2020-12-27', 'Guitar consists of a hollow wooden body with six strings stretched over it and along a narrow neck.', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/guitar1.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('04', 'Dumpling', '19.00', 'Food&Beverages', '2020-12-28', 'Dumpling consists of prawn', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/dumpling.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('05', 'Headset', '209.00', 'Others', '2020-12-28', 'Headset', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/headset.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('06', 'Badminton Racquet', '259.00', 'Others', '2020-12-28', 'Yonex Badminton Racquet', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/badminton1.jpeg'));
INSERT INTO `product`.`product` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `product_category`, `product_date`, `product_description`, `product_pic`) VALUES ('07', 'Introduction to Software Engineering', '159.00', 'Books&Stationery', '2020-12-29', 'A book which can used by Software Engineering from first year to last year', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/Khor Jia Cheng/Desktop/202009/Java EE/Project/images/book1.jpeg'));
```

But when I insert the value with LOAD_FILE it pops out the column cannot be null..Why?
[NULL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvyF1.png)

Comment: Please add the load_file command you used.

Comment: This query is running fine. Your problem must be somewhere else

Comment: I have added my load_file command. Can you guys help to check?

Comment: Have you checked that you meet all the pre-conditions described here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: Yea I can load the image with load value from file but not with sql